# Averaging error Haskell

Tags: haskell, average

I have created two functions below, one which gets the films of the director and another which gives the average.

The function which is giving me the problem is the directorAverage stating i have too few arguments. Am i missing something that is needed?

```
import Data.List 
import Text.Printf
import Data.Ord
import Data.Char

type Rating = (String, Int)
type Title = String
type Director = String
type Year = Int
type Film = (Title, Director, Year,[Rating])

testDatabase :: [Film]
testDatabase = [("Blade Runner","Ridley Scott",1982,[("Amy",6), ("Bill",9), ("Ian",7), ("Kevin",9), ("Emma",4), ("Sam",5), ("Megan",4)]),
                ("The Fly","David Cronenberg",1986,[("Megan",4), ("Fred",7), ("Chris",5), ("Ian",0), ("Amy",5)]),
                ("Psycho","Alfred Hitchcock",1960,[("Bill",4), ("Jo",4), ("Garry",8), ("Kevin",7), ("Olga",8), ("Liz",10), ("Ian",9)]),
                ("Body Of Lies","Ridley Scott",2008,[("Sam",3), ("Neal",7), ("Kevin",2), ("Chris",5), ("Olga",6)]),
                ("Avatar","James Cameron",2009,[("Olga",2), ("Wally",8), ("Megan",9), ("Tim",5), ("Zoe",8), ("Emma",3)]),
                ("Titanic","James Cameron",1997,[("Zoe",7), ("Amy",2), ("Emma",5), ("Heidi",3), ("Jo",8), ("Megan",5), ("Olga",7), ("Tim",10)]),
                ("The Departed","Martin Scorsese",2006,[("Heidi",2), ("Jo",8), ("Megan",5), ("Tim",2), ("Fred",5)]),
                ("Aliens","Ridley Scott",1986,[("Fred",8), ("Dave",6), ("Amy",10), ("Bill",7), ("Wally",2), ("Zoe",5)]),
                ("Prometheus","Ridley Scott",2012,[("Garry",3), ("Chris",4), ("Emma",5), ("Bill",1), ("Dave",3)]),
                ("E.T. The Extra-Terrestrial","Steven Spielberg",1982,[("Ian",7), ("Amy",2), ("Emma",7), ("Sam",8), ("Wally",5), ("Zoe",6)]),
                ("The Birds","Alfred Hitchcock",1963,[("Garry",7), ("Kevin",9), ("Olga",4), ("Tim",7), ("Wally",3)]),
                ("Goodfellas","Martin Scorsese",1990,[("Emma",7), ("Sam",9), ("Wally",5), ("Dave",3)]),
                ("The Shawshank Redemption","Frank Darabont",1994,[("Jo",8), ("Sam",10), ("Zoe",3), ("Dave",7), ("Emma",3), ("Garry",10), ("Kevin",7)]),
                ("Gladiator","Ridley Scott",2000,[("Garry",7), ("Ian",4), ("Neal",6), ("Wally",3), ("Emma",4)]),
                ("The Green Mile","Frank Darabont",1999,[("Sam",3), ("Zoe",4), ("Dave",8), ("Wally",5), ("Jo",5)]),
                ("True Lies","James Cameron",1994,[("Dave",3), ("Kevin",4), ("Jo",0)]),
                ("Minority Report","Steven Spielberg",2002,[("Dave",5), ("Garry",6), ("Megan",2), ("Sam",7), ("Wally",8)]),
                ("The Wolf of Wall Street","Martin Scorsese",2013,[("Dave",6), ("Garry",6), ("Megan",0), ("Sam",4)]),
                ("War Horse","Steven Spielberg",2011,[("Dave",6), ("Garry",6), ("Megan",3), ("Sam",7), ("Wally",8), ("Zoe",8)]),
                ("Lincoln","Steven Spielberg",2012,[("Ian",3), ("Sam",7), ("Wally",3), ("Zoe",4), ("Liz",7), ("Megan",4)]),
                ("Vertigo","Alfred Hitchcock",1958,[("Bill",7), ("Emma",5), ("Zoe",9), ("Olga",6), ("Tim",10)]),
                ("The Terminal","Steven Spielberg",2004,[("Olga",3), ("Heidi",8), ("Bill",2), ("Sam",6), ("Garry",8)]),
                ("Jaws","Steven Spielberg",1975,[("Fred",3), ("Garry",0), ("Jo",3), ("Neal",9), ("Emma",7)]),
                ("Hugo","Martin Scorsese",2011,[("Sam",4), ("Wally",3), ("Zoe",4), ("Liz",7)])]         

--Some functions needed later on:
averageFilmRating :: [(String,Int)] -> Float
averageFilmRating ratings
     = (fromIntegral(sum $ map snd ratings)) / (fromIntegral(length ratings))

--Shows films by director name
displayByDirector :: String -> [Film] -> [Film]
displayByDirector name database
     =  filter(\(_,director,_,_) -> director == name) database

--Gives the average of directors films//Giving Error seems ive missed something 
directorAverage :: String -> Float
directorAverage dir
     = averageFilmRating [rating | (title, director, year, ratings) <- displayByDirector dir, rating <- ratings]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`displayByDirector` has two arguments but you are only providing one. You could add a film list argument to director average:

```
directorAverage :: String -> [Film] -> Float
directorAverage dir database
     = averageFilmRating [rating | (title, director, year, ratings) <- displayByDirector dir database, rating <- ratings]
```

or you could use the test database

```
directorAverage :: String -> Float
    directorAverage dir
         = averageFilmRating [rating | (title, director, year, ratings) <- displayByDirector dir testDatabase, rating <- ratings]
```

Comment: -______________- i did exactly the first way but put a , between dir database. Such a silly mistake haha thanks!